# How do "avoid a blow" edges affect the outcome of other moves?

Tags: kult, kult-divinity-lost

In *Kult: Divinity Lost*, several Advantages can grant you combat edge that allows you to "avoid" or "block" an attack (Field Agent, Lightning Fast, Martial Arts Expert, Street Fighter).

Can you mix these with moves like Act Under Pressure or Engage in Combat to avoid failure/partial consequences, or are they limited to consequences from GM moves?

For example, if I've got edge from Field Agent and I roll 10-14 to Engage in Combat in a firefight, can I invoke "Take cover: avoid a ranged attack by diving behind an object or a person" to negate the "You’re subjected to a counterattack" complication for my partial success?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Edges* in this case works as *automatically successes*, because the player already earned them by succeeding on a prior test. Remember that these Advantages ask for a test and allows the GM to make a Move in case of failure, so they have a chance of making things even worse.

For when to use the *Edge*, it is a player decision, and it could be used to either avoid a *Consequence* from a partial success or even a *GM Move*, whenever the description fits.

In your example:

> For example, if I've got an edge from Field Agent and I roll 10-14 to Engage in Combat in a firefight, can I invoke "Take cover: avoid a ranged attack by diving behind an object or a person" to negate the "You’re subjected to a counterattack" complication for my partial success?

Yes, you can.

This is clearly a minor use of the Edge than avoiding a GM Move (which would usually *hit harder*), but if the player is happy to expend the Edge this way it is their choice.